# How to make In WPF an image box control that displays each pixel by itself?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I want to display a small picture on a large window, for example an image of 32X32 on a window of 800X800.

If I use a WPF standard `Image` control I get an unclear appearance, however in Visual Studio image editor each pixel looks on its own. 
With a clear border between pixels.

I want to make an image box in WPF that will display each pixel in its own right and like the Visual Studio
And perhaps there is such a control already exists? I'll be happy to know.

In Visual Studio image editor:
[image]

In standard `Image` control:
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn Now the question is clear?

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: I searched Google and did not find such a control ready, nor did anyone ask such a question
And I do not know how to start doing such a thing correctly.

Comment: Can you try adding RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" to your image control?

Comment: @BrunoV Excellent, it did it!

Comment: If you're actually looking to make a full-blown image editor, you may find [this answer to another question useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48448757/175070).

Comment: @DownVoter Are you sure?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"` will render the image pixelated:

```
<Image Width="800" Height="800" Source="[path]" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"></Image>
```